send message with cboden/ratchet
I'm pretty new to PHP/Laravel, i'm trying to set up a websocket using cboden/ratchet library. I did follow the instruction from the official docs and can hook up the process when trying to send message from Postman and receive then display in Frontend using VueJS.
This is the code for the Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

/**
 * @author Rohit Dhiman | @aimflaiims
 */
class WebSocketController implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;
    private $subscriptions;
    private $users;
    private $userresources;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->subscriptions = [];
        $this->users = [];
        $this->userresources = [];
    }

    /**
     * [onOpen description]
     * @method onOpen
     * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn [description]
     * @return [JSON]                    [description]
     * @example connection               var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8090');
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has connected\n";
        $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
    }

    /**
     * [onMessage description]
     * @method onMessage
     * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn [description]
     * @param  [JSON.stringify]              $msg  [description]
     * @return [JSON]                    [description]
     * @example subscribe                conn.send(JSON.stringify({command: "subscribe", channel: "global"}));
     * @example groupchat                conn.send(JSON.stringify({command: "groupchat", message: "hello glob", channel: "global"}));
     * @example message                  conn.send(JSON.stringify({command: "message", to: "1", from: "9", message: "it needs xss protection"}));
     * @example register                 conn.send(JSON.stringify({command: "register", userId: 9}));
     */
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg)
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($conn !== $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
        unset($this->users[$conn->resourceId]);
        unset($this->subscriptions[$conn->resourceId]);

        foreach ($this->userresources as &$userId) {
            foreach ($userId as $key => $resourceId) {
                if ($resourceId == $conn->resourceId) {
                    unset($userId[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }

    public function send($message)
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {

            $client->send($message);
        }
    }
}

and then the code for FE part:
       testCbodenSocket() {
            var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090");
            // var socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8091");
            // Connection opened
            socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                console.log(event);
                this.test = event.data;
            });
        },

Problem is that, i only need to send some notifications from backend to frontend through this so i hooked up the send() function in the controller to send automatically when it was called, but when i tried to run the function with php artisan tinker to test, it did not send anything.
Am i messing up anywhere ? As from my understand, if i called the send() function anywhere inside the backend, it would send the messages I put inside. Please correct me anywhere if i were wrong, thank you so much
Update: I have read about something call Push Integration from the docs but can not even install the ZMQ for php8.1.17 laravel 9, anyone have any ideas to the problem ?
